# Page is cutting at the bottom in memoir after adding hyperref package?

Tags: table-of-contents, memoir

Only the starting page of every chapter is getting cut. Everything was fine until I added hyperref package. Following is the initial code

```
\documentclass[10pt,twoside,openright]{memoir}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\usepackage{cases}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
    citecolor=black,
    filecolor=black,
    linkcolor=black,
    urlcolor=black
}

\geometry{ a4paper, top = 1in, bottom = 1in, left = 1.5in, right = 1.5in}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{observation}[theorem]{Observation}
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Definition}
\newtheorem{claim}[theorem]{Claim}
\newtheorem{fact}[theorem]{Fact}
\newtheorem{assumption}[theorem]{Assumption}

%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

%\usepackage{mathpazo}
\usepackage[protrusion=true,expansion=true]{microtype}
%\usepackage{type1cm}
%\usepackage{lettrine}

%\checkandfixthelayout

% See the ``Memoir customise'' template for some common customisations
% Don't forget to read the Memoir manual: memman.pdf

%\title{TITLE OF BOOK}
%\author{NAME OF AUTHOR}
%\date{} % Delete this line to display the current date

%% BEGIN TITLE

\makeatletter
\def\maketitle{%
  \null
  \thispagestyle{empty}%
  \vfill
  \begin{center}\leavevmode
    \normalfont
    {\Huge\raggedleft \@author\par}%
    \hrulefill\par
    {\Huge\raggedright \@title\par}%
    \vskip 1cm
%    {\Large \@date\par}%
  \end{center}%
  \vfill
    \null
}
\makeatother
\author{Vimal Raj Sharma}
\title{Notes on Algorithm}
\date{}

%%% BEGIN DOCUMENT

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\null\vfill

\mainmatter


\tableofcontents

\chapter{Analysis}

\section{Asymptotic notation}`
```

For instance, following is the problem.

[image]

Comment: can you please make your code  complete?

Comment: @touhami After the code there is nothing except sections and chapters. I can still add but I don't know how to post bulk code here, I manually added spaces in already written code.

Comment: @touhami Nevermind, got solved.

Answer (score 2):

The default paper format is `letterpaper` for class `memoir` (and the standard classes). Since LaTeX does not set the media size, this needs to be done by packages and classes like `memoir`, `hyperref`, `geometry`. The problem with the document is, that the paper size changed during the preamble. Therefore, it is better to add the correct paper size as early as possible:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, ...]{memoir}
```

Then `memoir` and `hyperref` can pick up the correct paper size.
The setting of the media size can also be disabled for `hyperref`:

```
\usepackage[setpagesize=false]{hyperref}
```

However, the global option is still needed, because of the class `memoir`.

---

The error because of duplicate destination name `page.1` can be avoided by disabling page anchors for the title pages:

```
\begingroup
  \hypersetup{pageanchor=false}
  \maketitle
  \cleardoublepage
\endgroup

\mainmatter
```